# Variables in Shiny to a sourced file via environment

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to build a small shiny app that will call a sourced file once an actionButton is pressed. The actionButton observer will capture the `input$topic` and `input$num` from the `ui.R` and then call this `source("downloadTweets.R")` file that needs the topic and num variables defined in the environment to work properly.

```
# Entry shiny server function
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$searchButton, {
    topic <- as.character(input$hashtagClass)
    num <- as.numeric(input$numTweetsClass)
    source("downloadTweets_Topic.R")
  })
})
```

When I try to run it, there is an error message that outputs that `topic` value was not found once the `source("downloadTweets_Topic.R")` call is made. I'm fairly new to Shiny, I read the scope documentation and use the `reactive()` function, but I'm afraid that I don't really get how it works. Is there a way to do this or should I reimplement the .R file so I can pass these values to a function?

The reason I'm doing it like this is just merely code reusal from a different project in R Studio which is not a Shiny app.

Comment: try `source("downloadTweets.R",local=TRUE)`, Note that a directory needs to be specified with the `source` too. Here I;m assuming that the file `downloadTweets.R` is in the same directory as the `server.r`

Comment: It shows the same problem as it looks like 'topic' and 'num' are not defined. The sourcing of the file works fine as the execution stack shows.

Comment: Without a proper example, it is hard to help you. please provide the source file and the input variables

Comment: `source(xx,local=TRUE)` fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `input$hashtagClass` is missing. Throw a `browser()` line above that line but inside the observe expression. This'll drop you into a breakpoint when the app is run and this code is triggered. You can likely solve the issue with a `req` call. Look it up with `?req`.

@pork chop's suggestion to add `local=T` to `source` is also important. This will put any assigned variables into the global env.